# intersection of null space of a complex matrix with a real set, real part of range of a complex matrix

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, reference-request

Suppose $A$ is a complex matrix, with range (column space) $\mathcal{R}(A)$
and nullspace $\mathcal{N}(A)$. Have these

$$\mathcal{N}(A) \cap \mathbb{R}^p$$

$$\Re(\mathcal{R}(A)) \quad \text{(real part of the column space)}$$

been considered in the literature? I'd appreciate a reference.